# Relacionamento com a mesma entidade MER

Tags: modelo-relacional, uml

Estou desenvolvendo meu tcc e me deparei com a seguinte dúvida em meu MER(Modelo entidade relacionamento).

Tenho uma entidade cliente que paga outro cliente, mas só que como eu represento isso no ER?

Tipo assim que estou falando:

```
CLIENTE (nenhum,muitos)  ---- PAGA ---- (nenhum,muitos) CLIENTE
```

Ficaria dessa forma mesmo?

Comment: Isto não seria um auto relacionamento? Cliente > Paga > Cliente, do jeito que você descreveu. No entanto, não é necessário criar outra entidade, a seta de associação volta pro próprio cliente,

Comment: Realmento isso me passou pela cabeça, mas os exemplos que vejo só mostram coisa relacionadas a cliente > supervisiona > cliente, coisas assim. E outra, o relacionamento tambem viraria uma tabela por causa da cardinalidade. Tem algum problema quando eu for colocar as chaves estrangeiras dentro da tabela PAGA?

Comment: Nenhum problema. Inclusive as chaves primária da tabela gerada pode ser composta pelos id de quem ta pagando e o id de quem recebe.

Comment: Ok, obrigado amigo.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214625/64969

Answer (score 1):

O livro afirma ser um relacionamento recursivo.

Acredito ser possível fazer uma comparação com o exemplo do livro [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz um desenho no draw.io para representar a resposta.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dessa forma é possível representar que existem N clientes que recebem remuneração de outros clientes, e que existe pelo menos 1 cliente que assume a posição de remunerador.

Vale ressaltar que o numero "1" no lado do remunerador indica que em uma transação somente pode existir 1 pessoa que está pagando a outra, ou seja, não da pra 2 ou mais pessoas realizarem um pagamento para uma mesma pessoa na forma de um único registro (isso não faz sentido)

Se uma pessoa (remunerado) está recebendo uma quantia de mais de uma pessoa(remunerador), então devem existir 2 registro distintos de pagamento.

A resposta veio do livro:Sistemas de banco de dados 5ª edição 
Autores: Elmasri, Ramez Navathe, Shamkant B.
Ano: 2011

Comment: Parabéns pela honestidade de por a fonte :-)