# Resgatar todos os nós de uma árvore do banco de dados SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, desserialização, árvore

Eu tenho uma árvore serializada no meu banco de dados na tabela `arvore`. Como toda boa árvore, todo nó pode ter, no máximo, um único nó pai. Seus dados são nesse formato:

```
id | id_pai | valor
---+--------+------
1  |        | 'pai de todos'
2  | 1      | 'um nó intermediário'
3  | 1      | 'irmão do outro'
4  | 2      | 'uma folha'
5  | 1      | 'outra folha'
6  |        | 'outra árvore'
7  | 6      | 'filho 1'
8  | 6      | 'filho 2'
```

A tabela acima é a serialização da floresta abaixo (apenas coloquei os ids nos nós):

```
   1       6
   |       |
+--+--+    +--+
|  |  |    |  |
2  3  5    7  8
|
4
```

Estou precisando selecionar apenas uma dessas árvores, dado apenas um único nó (é fornecido o ID desse nó na pesquisa). Como proceder?

Estou usando SQLite, mas se tiver uma solução em SQL pura será melhor ainda.

Comment: Relacionada: [Como selecionar registros em uma Tabela Auto referenciada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215916/64969)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para resolver isso, precisamos fazer uma consulta recursiva. Para fazer uma consulta recursiva, usamos a [Expressão Comum de Tabela (CTE)](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html).

> Note que a própria documentação do SQLite informa que CTEs fazem parte da especificação SQL:1999, portanto essa solução é padrão.
>
> Spoiler: para SQLServer, consultas recursivas se fazem somente com `WITH`, sem a palavra reservada `RECURSIVE`.
>
> MySQL 8 suporta consulta recursiva, de acordo com [essas](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-labs-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-mysql-ctes/) [referências](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html); MariaDB já suporta [desde a versão 10.2.2](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/with/).

Uma CTE parte de um conjunto básico e, então, se acrescenta a ele um conjunto recursivo/induzido. É um pensamento contrário da indução matemática, de onde o elemento básico é o último obtido. No nosso caso, o elemento básico é a raiz: `id_pai IS NULL`.

```
WITH RECURSIVE arvore_recursiva AS (
    /* conjunto base da recursão */
    SELECT
        id,
        id AS id_raiz,
        valor,
        0 AS profundidade
   FROM
        arvore
   WHERE
        id_pai IS NULL

   /* parte recursiva */
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
        this.id as id,
        ancestral.id_raiz as id_raiz,
        this.valor as valor,
        ancestral.profundidade + 1 AS profundidade
   FROM
       arvore this
       INNER JOIN arvore_recursiva ancestral
           ON (this.id_pai = ancestral.id)
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    arvore_recursiva
```

Assim, podemos dizer que todos que estejam na mesma árvore possuem o mesmo `id_raiz`. O resultado da consulta acima é:

```
id | id_raiz | valor                 | profundidade
---+---------+-----------------------+-------------
1  | 1       | 'pai de todos'        | 0
2  | 1       | 'um nó intermediário' | 1
3  | 1       | 'irmão do outro'      | 1
4  | 1       | 'uma folha'           | 2
5  | 1       | 'outra folha'         | 1
6  | 6       | 'outra árvore'        | 0
7  | 6       | 'filho 1'             | 1
8  | 6       | 'filho 2'             | 1
```

Para pegar todos os dados de uma árvore a partir de um único nó, podemos fazer uma auto junção da CTE nela mesma, já que é o mesmo problema resolvido [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214566/64969).

A ideia aqui é identificar a partir de um nó qual sua árvore e, então, selecionar todos os elementos dessa árvore:

```
WITH RECURSIVE arvore_recursiva AS (
    /* conjunto base da recursão */
    SELECT
        id,
        id AS id_raiz,
        valor,
        0 AS profundidade
   FROM
        arvore
   WHERE
        id_pai IS NULL

   /* parte recursiva */
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
        this.id as id,
        ancestral.id_raiz as id_raiz,
        this.valor as valor,
        ancestral.profundidade + 1 AS profundidade
   FROM
       arvore this
       INNER JOIN arvore_recursiva ancestral
           ON (this.id_pai = ancestral.id)
)
SELECT
    resto_arvore.*
FROM
    arvore_recursiva no_conhecido
    INNER JOIN arvore_recursiva resto_arvore
        ON (no_conhecido.id_raiz = resto_arvore.id_raiz)
WHERE
    no_conhecido.id = <ID DO NÓ CONHECIDO>
```

Comment: Bacana demais @Jefferson, deixo meu mais 1. Obrigado

Comment: @Marconi, vamos aumentando o conhecimento do mundo =D

Comment: Concerteza Jefferson!