# Sqlite consulta recursiva

Tags: query, sqlite, recursão

Estou iniciando com sqlite e gostaria de ajuda com uma consulta recursiva.

Tenho 3 tabelas (exemplo genérico):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab_componente (
        id_comp TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        desc_comp TEXT ,
        custo_comp INTEGER);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab_montagem (
        id_mont TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        desc_mont TEXT);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab_mont_itens (
        id_item TEXT NOT NULL,
        id_parent TEXT NOT NULL,
        tipo TEXT,
        quant INTEGER NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO tab_componente(id_comp, desc_comp, custo_comp)
VALUES ('comp1', 'componente 1', 1.00), 
       ('comp2', 'componente 2', 1.00), 
       ('comp3', 'componente 3', 1.00), 
       ('comp4', 'componente 4', 1.00), 
       ('comp5', 'componente 5', 1.00), 
       ('comp6', 'componente 6', 1.00),
       ('comp7', 'componente 7', 2.00), 
       ('comp8', 'componente 8', 1.00);

INSERT INTO tab_montagem(id_mont, desc_mont)
VALUES ('mont1', 'montagem 1'), 
       ('mont2', 'montagem 2'), 
       ('mont3', 'montagem 3'), 
       ('mont4', 'montagem 4'), 
       ('mont5', 'montagem 5');

INSERT INTO tab_mont_itens (id_item, id_parent, tipo, quant)  
VALUES
('comp1', 'mont1', 'componente' ,1.00),
('comp2', 'mont1', 'componente', 1.00),
('comp3', 'mont1', 'componente', 1.00),

('comp2', 'mont2', 'componente', 1.00),

('comp4', 'mont3', 'componente' ,1.00),
('comp5', 'mont3', 'componente', 1.00),
('comp7', 'mont3', 'componente', 1.00), 

('comp6', 'mont4', 'componente', 1.00),
('comp8', 'mont4', 'componente', 1.00),

('comp7', 'mont5', 'componente' ,1.00),      

('mont4', 'mont2', 'montagem', 2.00), 
('mont4', 'mont3', 'montagem', 3.00),
('mont5', 'mont2', 'montagem', 1.00),
('mont5', 'mont3', 'montagem', 1.00);
```

Trata-se de uma estrutura em árvore com montagens e sub-montagens:

- mont1

  - comp1
  - comp2
  - comp3
- mont2

  - comp2
  - mont4      (quant = 2)

    - comp6
    - comp8
  - mont5

    - comp7
- mont3

  - comp4
  - comp5
  - comp7
  - mont4      (quant = 3)

    - comp6
    - comp8
  - mont5

    - comp7

A query recursiva para uma montagem específica funciona corretamente mostrando a soma dos componentes e sub-componentes, por exemplo:

```
WITH RECURSIVE descendentes AS 
(SELECT id_parent AS parent, id_item AS descendente, quant, tipo FROM tab_mont_itens
UNION ALL 
SELECT d.parent, p.id_item, p.quant*d.quant, p.tipo
FROM descendentes AS d
INNER JOIN tab_mont_itens AS p
ON d.descendente = p.id_parent)
SELECT parent,descendente, SUM(quant), tipo FROM descendentes
WHERE parent = 'mont2' AND tipo = 'componente'
GROUP BY descendente
```

Mas meu objetivo é mostrar o custo total por componente, com todas as montagens, então tentei da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT id_comp,custo_comp, t.soma_comp,(custo_comp*t.soma_comp) AS custo FROM tab_componente
INNER JOIN
(WITH RECURSIVE descendentes AS (
SELECT id_parent AS parent, id_item AS descendente, quant, tipo FROM tab_mont_itens
UNION ALL 
SELECT d.parent, p.id_item, p.quant*d.quant, p.tipo
FROM descendentes AS d
INNER JOIN tab_mont_itens AS p
ON d.descendente = p.id_parent)
SELECT descendente, SUM(quant) AS soma_comp, tipo FROM descendentes
WHERE tipo = 'componente'
GROUP BY descendente) AS t ON id_comp = t.descendente
GROUP BY id_comp
```

Mas o resultado apresenta as somas corretas dos componentes 1 até o 5 e os componentes 6, 7 e 8 com valores errados (somando +1 ?).

Alguém pode me indicar o que estou fazendo de errado, ou me dar uma sugestão de como fazer isso de outra forma?

Comment: Relacionada? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214625/64969

Comment: Obrigado Jefferson, pela edição e pelas respostas. Consegui entender a recursão graças á sua resposta nesse link. O problema aparece  quando retiro a restrição da cáusula where para o id  específico.