# Consulta Recursivas para descobrir o item Pai

Tags: sql, oracle

Estou com a seguinte dúvida abaixo ao fazer a consulta no Oracle 10G.

Tenho a tabela `med_item_avaliar` que possui em sua estrutura itens que referenciam outros itens dentro dela mesma (Pais e Filhos).

Ao fazer a consulta simples é tranquilo, os itens acima são retornados, no entanto, ao tentar fazer a consulta ligando o item a ser avaliado à tabela de Resultados, nessa de Resultados eu não estou conseguindo trazer o item Pai, apenas o filho pelo fato de sua ligação estar se dando pelos filhos.

A consulta abaixo refere-se a tabela em questão:

```
select 
 t.nr_sequencia nr_sequencia_tipo,  
 t.ds_tipo ds_tipo,  
 i.ds_item ds_item,  
 i.nr_seq_tipo,  
 i.nr_sequencia nr_sequencia_item,  --aqui fica o item   
 i.nr_seq_superior                  --aqui fica a posição acima 

from med_tipo_avaliacao t,   
     med_item_avaliar i  

where t.nr_sequencia = i.nr_seq_tipo  
and t.nr_sequencia = 2281;
```

[image: Resultado consulta tabela]

Abaixo a pesquisa que estou tentando fazer buscando os itens que foram respondidos. A questão é que faltam os Pais desses itens.

```
--select dos itens  
FROM
    med_avaliacao_paciente   a, -- aqui o cabeçalho da avaliação no atendimento  
    med_avaliacao_result     b, -- aqui o resultado da avaliação, liga-se com o cabeçalho  
    pessoa_fisica            c, -- aqui o cadastro da PF pra pegar o nome  
    med_tipo_avaliacao       d, -- aqui fica o tipo de avaliação  
    med_item_avaliar         e  -- aqui o item do tipo  

WHERE
    a.nr_sequencia = b.nr_seq_avaliacao  
    AND d.nr_sequencia = e.nr_seq_tipo           --ligar o tipo de avaliação ao item  
    AND d.nr_sequencia = a.nr_seq_tipo_avaliacao  -- ligar o tipo de avalização ao tipo de atendimento  
    AND b.nr_seq_item = e.nr_sequencia           -- ligar o item da pesquisa ao item respondido  
    AND b.nr_seq_avaliacao = 1377920  
    AND d.nr_sequencia = 2281  
    AND a.nr_atendimento = 2147535;
```

Dessa forma estou apenas pegando os itens que foram respondidos, mas não sei qual é o Pai desse item, apenas o item respondido que varia entre: Adequado, Inadequado, conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: Resultado consulta sem o Pai]

Como trazer também o Pai dos filhos nessa consulta e que realmente corresponda aos filhos?

Comment: Oracle, pelo que me lembre, permite declarar CTEs recursivas. CTE é aquela cláusula DML antes do _insert_, _update_, _delete_ ou _select_ que começa com `with`

Comment: Isto daqui foi feito para SQLite, mas creio que pode ser usada quase igual com Oracle: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214626/64969

Comment: Recursivo no ORACLE , use CONNECT BY

Comment: Você precisa usar um `WITH` como o @JeffersonQuesado havia comentado

Comment: @Motta eu adoraria ver um exemplo, não conheço essa construção.

Comment: https://www.devmedia.com.br/uso-do-connect-by-no-oracle/23647

Answer (score 0):

Se a tabela é filha dela mesma (FK para a mesma tabela), tente apenas realizar um subselect pegando o campo descrição, referenciando a PK da tabela do subselect com o campo da FK da tabela pai.

```
(SELECT filha.ds_item
FROM med_item_avaliar filha
WHERE filha.nr_sequencia = pai.nr_seq_superior) item_superior,
```